# Except first prefix,how do i match the rest of the data

Tags: mysql

For instance-

```
Location
B014130030
SS010111
MA01
MA01
SMA01
```

Consider Column as Location table name say ORDERSHIPMENT- I'm trying to compare MA01 with SMA01 so ignoring the first prefix 'S',now rest of the word should match,and my query should return
count(distinct location) as = 3

Comment: Normalise your data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to match `MA01` appearing either at the start of the location, or with an optional single leading character, you may try using `REGEXP`:

```
SELECT Location
FROM yourTable
WHERE Location REGEXP '^.?MA01';
```

### Demo

Comment: I want to fetch distinct records based on columns and if the set of records dosen't match i should again fetch distinct records but now removing the 1st Prefix(S) from (SMA01),and again matching(MA01,MA01) now can get distinct out of it and there is bulk of records like this

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add sample data and expected output which explains exactly what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wildcard for this:

```
SELECT Location
FROM ORDERSHIPMENT
WHERE Location LIKE '%MA01';
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `like` operator to do that.

`like` operator matches character pattern. What do you have common in `MA01` and `SMA01` is `MA01`. So you need to match character pattern where `MA01` occurs. To skip the preceding character(s) which is `S` you need to use `%` and put it in front of `MA01` - `%MA01`.

*Bonus: If there are character after `MA01` such as `MA01S`, you have to put the `%` later - `MA01%`*

```
select count(*) from order_shipment where location like '%MA01';
```

See the full implementation here - [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66fe1c/2).

Comment: This skips an infinite number of prefixes before 'M'

Comment: @Strawberry thanks for noting the obvious. OP said there will be one char before `M`. This should not cause any significant efficiency problem.